# Is there anyway to load a .tflite without keras or tensorflow in python android app?

Tags: android, tensorflow, model, tensorflow-lite

I'm fairly new to this so please excuse mylack of knowledge. I'm trying to make an ML app with kivy, which detects certain objects. The problem is that I cannot include tensorflow and keras in my code because kivy doesn't allow apk conversion with it. So I came across tensorflow lite, which can run on android, but when I looked at a python example for it, I found out that it includes tensorflow-

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
const = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.]) + tf.constant([1., 4., 4.])
val = img + const
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

# Convert to TF Lite format
with tf.Session() as sess:
  converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [img], [out])
  tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

So I was wondering if there is any way I can use my model in android, built on python?

Comment: Do you want to use the model in an Android app or in Python?

Comment: I mean, of course in the Andoid App. But it is made in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The easiest way is using TensorFlow Lite [Java API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/package-summary), and it does not depend on TensorFlow or Keras at all.

You can also read the TensorFlow Lite Android quick start [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android)